# Nginx with varnish error: failed (24: Too many open files)

Tags: sockets, nginx, proxy, varnish, varnish-4

I am running varnish with nginx as proxy on ubuntu and I am getting (24: Too many open files) error every few days. 
Restarting nginx solves the problem.
After researching about this error I found that the common solution is to increase worker_rlimit_nofile in nginx.conf.
I feel like this is not a real solution since the limit I will set might reach as well.

Why nginx keeps these files (I believe these are the sockets) open? and what will a solution to my situation?

UPDATE:

I just noticed there are hundreds of varnish sockets open when I run lsof. I believe my issue is that these sockets don't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to increase the standard max number of files open on your server when it is a web server, the same goes for the number of ephemeral ports.

I think the default number of opened files is 1024 which is way too small for varnish

I am setting it to 131072

`ulimit -n 131072`

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I wondered why these sockets stay open. I stoped passing traffic to the varnish server few days ago and I still see these sockets open and get the same error (24: Too many open files)

Comment: I'm no varnish developer but I think each varnish thread manages a socket and since varnish spawns lots of threads (no harm, it's optimized), it needs lots of sockets. If you look at varnish service configuration you should see somewhere `# Open files (usually 1024, which is way too small for varnish)
        ulimit -n ${NFILES:-131072}`